# Sort a dict by keys, assuming keys are orderable

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, hash-map, collections

I found a suspicious code snipped in an existing project in which I am involved as a developer. The code sorts a `dict` by its keys, so that if iterated over the dict, the elements are returned in the sorted order.
In order to have some stand-alone code I refactored out a function which does that job.
However, as I was suspicious about the existing implementation I wrote a second stand-alone function which does the same job but a little different.

Please review my two implementations from which I will improve the better one given the suggestions and then add it to the project.
The performance and number of statements within the function does not matter so much in this case. However, I need to be sure that the items in the `dict` are returned in the correct order when iterating over it.

1.)

```py
def sort_dct1(dct: dict) -> dict:
    return dict(sorted(dct.items()))
```

Test:

```py
print(sort_dct({3: 100, 2: 10, 44: 20, 1: 80}))  # just for testing

> {1: 80, 2: 10, 3: 100, 44: 20}
```

2.)

```py
import collections

def sort_dct2(dct: dict) -> collections.OrderedDict:
    return collections.OrderedDict(sorted(dct.items()))
```

Test:

```py
print(sort_dct2({3: 100, 2: 10, 44: 20, 1: 80}))

> OrderedDict([(1, 80), (2, 10), (3, 100), (44, 20)])
```

The second implementation also passes the `isinstance` test:

```py
isinstance(sort_dct2({3: 100, 2: 10, 44: 20, 1: 80}), dict)
True
```

Comment: Neither implementation sorts the dict by its *keys*. Both implementations *also* take into consideration the *values*, since both algorithms sort by the dict's *items*, which are tuples of `(key, value)` pairs. The outcome is still the same as sorting by keys only, since the keys in a dict are guaranteed to be unique, but still...

Comment: So you would say, I should extract keys, sort by those and then reassign values in the sorted order?

Comment: Also, in your title you talk about sorting by *keys* whereas in your question's body you assert that the algorithm sorts by *value* which is not true at all.

Comment: That depends on the use case. Depending on the actual dict's *values* sorting by *items* might be slower than only sorting by *keys*. You've given too little context for me to recommend anything.

Comment: Sorry, as `key` and `value` are standing concepts and I wanted to say that I wanted to sort by the "value" of the keys and not by the "values" in the dict, I should clarify. Will update the question.

Comment: More context would be helpful. Is the `dict` kept sorted all (or most of) the time? Or is it just sorted before certain operations (like printing)?

Comment: It's just for printing purposes. The dict is used to manage ports with certain capabilities in a testing system, e.g. a dict1 with ports having capabilities1, dict2 with ports having capabilities2. Then the ports are mapped to some other parameters belonging to certain ports. Now, when in a UI a certain invalid parameter combination is selected, then I wanted the code to output which ports do not match the requested settings, so the user has a chance to correct his settings using a parameter combination matching all ports. This is just a shortcut but I hope it covers the most important aspects

Answer (score 3):

python dictionaries (`dict`) can only be assumed to retain their order for python 3.7 and later. For earlier versions of python it is implementation dependent, if order is retained.
Sometimes it might work, sometimes it does not.

This means unless you can guarantee, that you run on python >= 3.7, the first code might introduce very nasty dangerous bugs.

Even if you guarantee that you run on python 3.7, it would be nice to know that you rely on order. Instead of writing a comment the `collections.OrderedDict` is self-documenting and tells any future developer that you indeed need order.
It also tells other libraries in the python ecosystem, that they should preserve the order of the dictionary.
This is for example the case for `pandas.DataFrames`, when they are initialized from dictionaries.

So all in all, I would go for the second option.

As mentioned already in the comments, you are not sorting by key, but by a `(key, value)` pair.

Comment: Yeah, I was also thinking about being more specific when using `OrderedDict`. However, I won't go for `pandas` because it would introduce another dependency. I don't refrain it totally, it's just beyond scope of my goal. Anyway, it's good to know for future.

Answer (score 1):

The second implementation using `collections.OrderedDict` is better in my opinion for all the reasons mentioned by @mcocdawc.

Additionally, in the sake of reusability, I would suggest changing the API to match the built-in `sorted()` function and documenting your method:

- rename `sort_dct` to `sorted_dict`: the built-in `sort` function sorts iterables in place, and `sorted` creates a sorted copy. It's always good to follow existing conventions
- Allow passing a `key` and a `reverse` flag
- Add a docstring

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def sorted_dict(dictionary, /, *, key=None, reverse=False) -> OrderedDict:
    '''
    Return a new OrderedDict containing all items from the dictionary in
    ascending key order

    A custom key function can be supplied to customize the sort order, and the
    reverse flag can be set to request the result in descending order.
    '''
    return OrderedDict(sorted(dictionary.items(), key=key, reverse=reverse))
```

Notes:

- the `/` and `*` in the signature denote that arguments before the `/` are positional only and those after the `*` are keyword only, matching the signature of the built-in `sorted()` function
- using the `key` is kind of janky, as `items()` returns a interable of tuples. This could maybe be improved by unpacking `items` into a `namedTuple`, improving the docstring, or some other way, but I went for simplicity here
- With very minor changes you could implement a `sort_dict` function for in-place sorting

Usage:

```
>>> foo = {1: 'a', 3: 'b', 2: 'c'}
>>> sorted_dict(foo)
OrderedDict([(1, 'a'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'b')])
>>> sorted_dict(foo, reverse=True)
OrderedDict([(3, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (1, 'a')])
>>> sorted_dict(foo, key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)
OrderedDict([(2, 'c'), (3, 'b'), (1, 'a')])
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `, *,` instead of `/, *,`? Thank you about the hint on `sort` via `sorted`. Would it be possible to use `lambda tup: tup[0]` as the `key` argument to `sorted`, according to _Example 3: Sort the list using sorted() having a key function_, https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/sorted?

Comment: @LooserUser Omitting `/` means that parameters that come before `*` are positional-or-keyword, instead of positional only. See: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#special-parameters

It would also work, but I wanted to stay as close as I could to the `sorted` convention.

For the `key` argument, the argument name used in the lambda function doesn't matter, `tup` would works just as well as `item` or anything else. Note that using `tup[0]` uses the *dictionary* keys as the *sorting* key, which would have the same effect as the default sorting operation.

Comment: @RichardNeumann

As you said: _"Neither implementation sorts the dict by its keys. Both implementations also take into consideration the values, since both algorithms sort by the dict's items, which are tuples of (key, value) pairs."_ :

Would you prefer the lambda to clarify the dict is sorted by it's key and not by the `(key, value)`-pair?